# jetty can't load mysql jdbc driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jetty

I have included the mysql jdbc driver in my demo app.

```
/tmp/jettytmp$ find . -name "*.jar"
./jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-auth-0.1.war-_auth-any-7537667183570190622.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar
```

However, When I try to login my demo app, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException throws out:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.connectDatabase(JDBCLoginService.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.loadUser(JDBCLoginService.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.MappedLoginService.login(MappedLoginService.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.JDBCLoginService.login(JDBCLoginService.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.login(LoginAuthenticator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.login(FormAuthenticator.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.FormAuthenticator.validateRequest(FormAuthenticator.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-03-12 15:41:32.894:WARN:oejs.JDBCLoginService:qtp1980086877-13: UserRealm Admin Login could not load user information from database
java.sql.SQLException: Can't connect to database
```

From the log, we can see the JDBCLoginService try to connect to the database, but the jdbc driver is not found. But the jdbc driver has already been included in the demo app? how to solve this issue, any comments are appreciated.
My jetty verison is 9.2. And I using the following command to launch demo app:
java -jar /*/jetty-distribution-9.2.15.v20160210/start.jar

Answer (score 3):

You are using an outdated/historic package name for the MySQL driver. You should *update* it to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the configuration of your application, as documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager):

> With MySQL Connector/J, the name of this class is com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.

Having done this, it will be found if `mysql-connector-java-5.1.x.jar` is availble in the classpath at runtime.

Details for the configuration of the MySQL JDBC driver and it's usage can be found here at the official [MySQL Connector/J (JDBC) Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

The latest MySQL JDBC connector is available for [download here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).